# Wordpress Database Import

Tags: database, wordpress, import

I just imported my Wordpress database from a localhost installation on my computer to the online server. However, all the links still point to localhost instead of the server's url.

Is there something extra I forgot to do?

(Note: I did not hard write my links so for example the navigation which still points to localhost is generated with this code:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li='); ?>
```

An other example is when I type the in url and type "wp-admin/" after it to access the dashboard, it redirects me to the localhost dashboard page....really weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to the `wp_options` table of your database (assuming `wp_` is your WordPress table prefix) and change the values of the fields with these option names, to reflect the location of your online server:

- siteurl
- home

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed the problem. Your my hero! :D

Answer (score 3):

You possibly need to fix your configuration file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

There are some values in the table `wp_options` that are URLs pointing to your site, and they need to be updated. To see which ones, do

```
select * from wp_options where option_value like 'http://%';
```

In my installation they are the rows where `option_name` is `siteurl` or `home`.